# Promise.allSettled - how to properly throw error?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, async-await, promise

I am using this to call Promise.allSettled. Success scenarios are coming through as expected

```
    let data = await Promise.allSettled(body.map(async (index) => {
        return apiHelper.get(index);
    }));
```

While testing a failure scenario, however, an error with status `rejected` is never added to `data`. In my apiHelper I have this error handling which the code reaches as expected

```
} catch (e) {
    throw new Error('Error during API Call: ' + e);
}
```

But the entire runtime fails with one single error message. Is there a correct way to handle errors with `async await` ? I've tried using `Promise.reject` in the catch block but I get the same issue every time.

Answer (score 0):

Try using try/catch like this

```
let data = await Promise.allSettled(body.map(async (index) => {
  try {
    return apiHelper.get(index);
  } catch (e) {
    // Handle the error here
    return Promise.reject(e);
  }
}));
```

Comment: Promise.allSettled(body.map((item) => what ever you want to do)).then((val) => console.log(val)).catch((err) => console.log(err))    try this way

Comment: Same issue. With this case it looks like the call returns before the api calls are finished running as well

Answer (score 0):

By inspecting the Settled Promise results from the allSettled invocation:

```js
export default async function allSettledAndThrow<T>(promises: Promise<T>[]): Promise<T[]> {
  const settledPromises = await Promise.allSettled(promises);
  const results: T[] = [];

  for (const settledPromise of settledPromises) {
    if (isRejectedPromise(settledPromise)) {
      throw new Error(settledPromise.reason);
    }

    results.push(settledPromise.value);
  }

  return results;
}

function isRejectedPromise<T>(promise: PromiseSettledResult<T>): promise is PromiseRejectedResult {
  return promise.status === 'rejected';
}
```